# cv:Mat, every second pixel is set

Tags: mat, computer-vision

I'm new to CV and I'm coming up with a question.
I want to create a fading grey bar (from black to white).

So i initializied a Mat:

```
Mat fadedgrey=Mat(20,256,CV_8UC1);
```

when I write the pixelvalues:

```
for(int x=0;x<20;x++){
   for(int y=0;y<256;y++){
    fadedgrey.at<int>(x,y)=y;}}
```

the result is the following:
only every second column is written, but I thought CV_8UC1 is one-channel, not a two-channel Mat.

For example the value set at Position (1,129) comes up with a Pixel in the beginning of second row.

Help me! 
Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is of type CV_8UC1, then each element is one byte in size and you should be using `.at<uchar>` or similar, rather than `.at<int>`.

Although this isn't your problem, you might also end-up confused about rows and columns, as your Mat constructor takes `nRows,nCols`, which is the opposite way around to `x,y`

Comment: actually the uchar datatype helped...the rest was try and error TY